# postgresql - export to csv - maximum characters per row

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

I'm using `postgresql 9.4` / `pgadminIII` to export a query to a `csv` file via the `COPY` command.

It's actually a concatenation of many columns (it's an input file for another program) and runs to several hundred characters in length (> 300 characters).  The query executes but when I look at the file it generates, the rows are cut off over 255 characters.

I know in `SQL Server` there is an option that needs to be set for how wide the output column to file is.

Is there a similar setting for `postgresql`?  Any other suggestions?

EDIT:

Here is the query:

```
copy (SELECT CASE WHEN cast(click as int) = 1 THEN 1
    ELSE -1
    END
    || ' '
    || id
    || '|'
    || 'hr_' || substring(hour, 7,8)
    || ' |dw_' || substring(to_char(to_date(substring(hour, 1,6),'YYMMDD'), 'dy'),1,2)
    || ' |C1_' || c1
    || ' |C14_' || c14
    || ' |C15_' || c15
    || ' |C16_' || c16
    || ' |C17_' || c17
    || ' |C18_' || c18
    || ' |C19_' || c19
    || ' |C20_' || c20
    || ' |C21_' || c21
    || ' |C22_' || substring(to_char(to_date(substring(hour, 1,6),'YYMMDD'), 'dy'),1,2) || '_' || substring(hour, 7,8)

  FROM train
  limit 10)  

  TO 'C:/me/train.csv' with csv;
```

Comment: I'm not sure quite what you're asking.  Why do you need this setting?  Are you unable to export the file as is? If so, what is THAT error?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: see edit above.  FYI, the query is being executed in pgAdmin query builder, not psql command line.

Comment: Still, the `copy` command writes the data on the server - regardless of the SQL client being used. Just to make sure we are not missing the obivous: did you run the query without the `copy` to verify that you do have values that are long than 255 characters? You can do a `select max(the_column) from (... your query here)` to check that

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: max() or max(length())?

Comment: `max(length(..))` obviously ;)  I just ran `copy (select rpad('x', 500, 'x') from generate_series(1,100)) to 'c:/temp/x.csv' with csv;` and all the lines where 500 characters long.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: just checking :) - max is actually 272.